# Trouble removing missing data from data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R so please excuse my very basic question:

I have a data frame that has a lot of missing data. I've used na.omit to remove missing data as in:

```
data2 <- na.omit(data1)
```

Howevever, some of the variables are factors that still seem to have "" as one of the categorise, as in:

```
> str(data2$smoker)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 ...
```

When I look at "data2" it does still have missing values. What I am doing wrong?

Help and advice much appreciated.

Greg

Comment: Unless you tell R to do so when reading in your file, `""` is not considered missing. How did you read in your data?

Comment: By default, `""` is not a missing value. Missing values are declared by the logical constant `NA` (see help `?NA`) or, in case of a character value, by `NA_character_`. You could e.g. try `na.omit(factor(data2$smoker, levels = c("No", "Yes")))`.

Comment: @Heroka - thanks - I simply did a read.csv

Comment: @lucaA - thanks - that seems to have helped a lot

Comment: @lukeA I seem to have a new problem now. If I try to create a table using one of the variables for which I have now removed all of the "" values, I get an error that states "all arguments must have the same length". Is there a way to remove all of the rows for which the "" was removed from a particular variable?

Comment: @drgregmartin yes. E.g. `df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = factor(c("", "yes", "no"))); df[df == ""] <- NA; na.omit(df); na_rows <- is.na(df$b); df[!na_rows, ]`. BTW: You should edit your question and provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`NA` is not the same as `""`.

What is the difference?

- `NA` indicates a missing value
- `""` is an empty string, which is a type of value

`na.omit` will remove `NA` values, but it will not remove empty strings.

I suggest turning `""` into `NA` before using `na.omit`:

```
data1[data1$smoker == "", "smoker"] <- NA
```

Comment: I think syntax like `is.na(data1$smoker) <- data1$smoker == ""` should also work.